# Show that $|\cos(x)| \geq 1 - \sin^2 (x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Show that $|\cos(x)| \geq 1 - \sin^2 (x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm using the graph of both $f(x) = |\cos(x)|$ and $f(x) = 1 - \sin^2 (x)$ only for showing, but I think it's doesn't enough. For $>$, some $x$ holds, for example: $x=\frac{2\pi}{3}$. I'm not able to show it completely. Any idea?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hint. Note that the RHS is $\cos^2(x)$ and $\cos(x)\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: @RobertZ Yes, I know it. But, what next?

Comment: I.e. $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$.

Comment: @C.F.G So? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Consider $\cos(x)^2 + \sin(x) ^2 = 1$ and also how $a$ relates to $a^2$ when $-1 \leq a \leq 1$.

Comment: $|\frac{1}{t}|\geq (\frac{1}{t})^2=\frac{1}{t^2}$.

Comment: Maybe it's even more intuitive to write it as $\lvert \cos x \rvert \ge \lvert \cos x \rvert ^2$. Now you only have to deal with nonnegative numbers. $\lvert \cos x \rvert$ can take on every value in the range $[0, 1]$, so can you prove the inequality $x \ge x^2$ for $x \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, I can. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to

$$|\cos x|\ge\cos^2x$$ or

$$|\cos x|(1-|\cos x|)\ge0,$$ which is true.

Comment: Do you mean: $|cos x|(|cos x| - 1) \leq 0$ ?

Comment: @user795084: oops, typo...

Comment: okay${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

On the interval $[0,1]$, one has $\sqrt x \ge x$, and $|\cos x|=\sqrt{\cos^2x}$.

Comment: On the interval $[0,1], \sqrt(x) \geq x$. From this, we have $|\cos (x)| = \sqrt(\cos^2 (x)) \geq \cos^2 (x)$.

Comment: @user795084: What's true (or not)?